# Java tracing confusion

Tags: java, trace

Can someone help me to understand why java is trying to make an instance of a before b. And also, why it is looping between line 2 and line 3?

```
public class Winterfell {

  private Winterfell a= new Winterfell();

    public Winterfell() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Fire and Ice");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Winterfell b = new Winterfell();
            System.out.println("Surprise!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("I told you so");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. It starts constructing the object for `b`, which requires constructing `a` first, so it starts constructing `a` too. That fails, so the whole process fails.

Comment: Since object a is a data member, so to completely instantiate b, we need an object of a.

Comment: Your terminology is bad. `a` is not a class so there is no "instance of a" and similarly for `b`.

Answer (score 3):

This will cause a `StackOverflowError`.

By having a field referencing a new object of the same class or by making a new object of the same class in the constructor you have an infinite number of calls to create a new `Winterfell` object.

That is why it is looping.

To fix this you likely want to remove `private Winterfell a= new Winterfell();` so that a single `Winterfell` object is created.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Winterfell a= new Winterfell();
```

Is invoked prior to invoking the constructor of `Winterfell` because it's a data member. Check out [the Oracle documentation for object construction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) for more info.